# Django Error code 28 while synchronizing the database (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

In django I create new models in existing database. While synchronizing the models it displays an error. I cannot fix these problem. I'm using mysql as database. I added the error code. Kindly share your ideas.

```
python manage.py syncdb
Creating tables ...
Creating table registration_securityquestions
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 459, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 102, in handle_noargs
    cursor.execute(statement)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 40, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 114, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 174, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: (3, "Error writing file './userregdb/registration_securityquestions.frm' (Errcode: 28)")
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [MySQL doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/cannot-create.html):

The preceding error is a typical message for Windows; the Unix message is similar.

One fix is to start mysqld with the `--tmpdir` option or to add the option to the `[mysqld]` section of your option file. For example, to specify a directory of `C:\temp`, use these lines:

```
[mysqld]
tmpdir=C:/temp
```